# Put missing double quotes in a JSON string value in java

Tags: java, json, regex, string, gson

I have a json string where all the values need to be surrounded with double quotes. for example (just a sample, it contains many similar fields)

```
    {"Id": "2017",
     "Currency": "AUD",
     "Date": 2020-06-22,
     "InCash": 0.000, 
     "Dep": "ABC90",
     "sumCash": 770.87,
     "AnotherDate": 2020-06-21}
```

to

```
     {"Id": "2017",
     "Currency": "AUD",
     "Date": "2020-06-22",
     "startCash": "0.000", 
     "Dep": "ABC90",
     "sumCash": "770.87",
     "AnotherDate": "2020-06-21"}
```

I am trying with regular expressions but its breaking the 'Date' fields.

```
jsonString.replaceAll(":[ ]*([\\w@\\.]+)", ": \"$1\"")
```

also tried with gson library, but its only putting the quotes on date values and not on the decimal values.

```
new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).toString()
```

What exactly I need to do to achieve it?

Comment: Where did the string come from? Given that this isn't valid JSON, could you try to get it fixed at source rather than applying a "fix-up" later? Aside from anything else, that way the originator gets to choose whether some things *don't* end up as strings - for example, the 0.000 and 770.87 *might* be deliberately non-string values (whereas 2020-06-22 is just wrong).

Comment: @JonSkeet its a fixed format Avro Object coming from a kafka topic, KStream<String, AvroObject>

Comment: I know very little about Avro, but is something converting it from Avro format into JSON? Because if so, it's clearly doing it badly, and I think that's worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: dont know whey it called JSON, it really a very simple structure, objects {} contain  key value pairs where values can be strings, or numbers, or arrays (lists of values), or objects, or true, false, or null. very simple to write a regex for it in PCRE, but java do not have function calls (ie. recursion). but for what yuior doing, whach not pasre JSON, do not need recursion. Big mistake to say  `JSON` some doomers have no opshuns but a real _**PARSER**_, but a joke cause it so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the below regex expression.

```
jsonString.replaceAll(": [ ]*([\\w@\\.-]+)", ": \"$1\""));
```

Thanks everyone for your help and support !

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
var newS = jsonString.replaceAll(": +((?!\\\\).*)(!?[,|}] *)", ": \"$1\"$2").replaceAll("\\\"\\\"","\"");
```

output

```
{
  "Id": "2017",
  "Currency": "AUD",
  "Date": "2020-06-22",
  "InCash": "0.000",
  "Dep": "ABC90",
  "sumCash": "770.87",
  "AnotherDate": "2020-06-21"
}
```

Comment: Not working. I got it fixed with this replaceAll(": [ ]*([\\w@\\.-]+)", ": \"$1\"")

Answer (score 0):

if the other JSON form (rules) of yuior string don't change, this will work for the
name - value form.
note - i did not do the part where it could be a string in a *list* but its doable alsero

Find:
`("\s*\w+\s*"\s*:(?!\s*")(?!\s*\d+\s*(?:,|\]|}))(?!\s*[{\[])(?!\s*(?:true|false|null)\s*(?:,|\]|}))\s*)(.+?)(?=[,}])`
Replace:
`$1"$2"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cLTbIa/1)

see my complete PCRE regex for parsing JSON a eally simple structure spec.
here https://regex101.com/r/H8datD/1 which is not available to java until regex engine uses recursion (functions).

note - when needing to change just one aspect of JSON where it otherwise is complient with the spec structure
it is easy to extract the code in my regex to get right down to the area of interest. it easy !